# Windows Phone 7: Detecting if a charger is plugged in

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How can I detect if a charger is plugged in, or unplugged? Preferably I would like to receive some trigger (anything like BroadcastListener in Android?), but polling could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to access this information at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the [DeviceStatus.PowerSourceChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.devicestatus.powersourcechanged.aspx)